# Expo: How to change the splash image programmatically?

Tags: expo, splash-screen

I have an React Native Expo app.json as below:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Awesome App",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.jpg",
    },
  ...
}
```

In my App, I want to allow user to select an image from the list of images (loaded from server) and that image will be shown in the splash screen next time when user start the App.

How can I do this with Expo?

Answer (score 0):

you will use react navigation. just add splashScreen in stackNavigator

```
export default StackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: { screen: SplashScreen },
  AuthScreen: { screen: AuthScreen },
  MainNavigator: { screen: MainNavigator }
}, {
  headerMode: 'screen',
  navigationOptions: {
    header: { visible: false }
  }
})
```

add timeout.In my case

```
componentDidUpdate () {
  if (this.state.isAppReady) {
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('MainNavigator');
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthScreen');
    }
  }
}
```

you can change image in rendering.

Comment: This approach is suitable after Expo loaded our App.